# Replace text field itext

Tags: pdf, replace, stream, itext

I trying to replace text of a PDF created by OpenOffice using the example of the oficial itext page but i can't

http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs-itext5/replacing-pdf-objects

I extract all the streams to a file but i don't localize the text that i want to replace.

This is an example of manipulate PDF:

```
public void manipulatePdf(PdfReader reader,String temp) throws IOException, DocumentException {

    PdfObject obj;
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getXrefSize(); i++) {
        obj = reader.getPdfObject(i);

        if (obj != null && obj.isStream()) {
             PRStream stream = (PRStream)obj;
             byte[] b;
             try {
                 b = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
                 String p = new String(b);                     
                 //stream.setData(new String(p).replace("firmantes", "HELLO WORLD").getBytes());
                 stream.setData(p.replace("HOLA MUNDO", "mamamamamamamam").getBytes());
             }
             catch(UnsupportedPdfException e) {
                 b = PdfReader.getStreamBytesRaw(stream);
             }
             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(String.format(DEST_STREAMS, i));
             fos.write(b);
             fos.flush();
             fos.close();
         }
      }
}
```

My document only have the text "HOLA MUNDO".

This is the stream that I think contains my data:

```
0.1 w
q 0 0.1 595.2 841.8 re
W* n
q 0 0 0 rg
BT
56.8 774.1 Td /F1 12 Tf[<01>-2<02>-2<03>2<04>55<0506>-2<07>5<08>-2<09>5<02>]TJ
ET
Q
Q
```

Why can't I see the text?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely, your text was "optimized" - converted into glyphs without mapping to original characters. "HOLA MUNDO" is depicted here in `[<01>-2<02>-2<03>2<04>55<0506>-2<07>5<08>-2<09>5<02>]` , with O being symbol <02> - note that it is reused in the last character.

Comment: @Lyth Not necessarily *without mapping to original characters*: I'm fairly optimistic that OpenOffice adds an adequate **ToUnicode** map to the matching font definition which allows text extraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use that iText example in real life unless you are sure that you only deal with documents which

1. use standard font encodings (**WinAnsiEncoding**, **MacRomanEncoding**);
2. use literal strings in their text drawing instruction arguments (not hexadecimal strings); and
3. put your place holders / character sequences to replace into a single text drawing instruction string argument.

While these assumptions were true in many PDF documents of the early PDF years, more and more documents break them nowadays. Some other PDF libraries, therefore, meanwhile have removed examples equivalent to the one you reference from their distributions and sites.

---

For your document actually none of the assumptions hold:

1. A custom, ad-hoc encoding is used:

   ```
   1 : "H"
   2 : "O"
   3 : "L"
   4 : "A"
   5 : " "
   6 : "M"
   7 : "U"
   8 : "N"
   9 : "D"
   ```

   Thus, "HOLA MUNDO" is encoded using the bytes 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 02. (This kind of ad-hoc encoding is often found for embedded font subsets.)
2. Hexadecimal strings are used (hex digits in angled brackets).
3. Only two glyphs of your search string, " M" = `<0506>`, are in the same single PDF string object, all others are separated by small displacements, most likely for kerning.